# Highlight table row background color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, background, html-table, highlight

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.21. I want to highlight a specific row in my table, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {      
     $('#tr635').effect("highlight", {}, 3000); 
});
</script>
```

`#tr635` is the id of the tr I wish to highlight. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

HTML code for the table:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="title">Prioritize Liabilities</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="info">Note</td>
    <td class="info">Balance</td>
    <td class="info">Total Debt</td>
    <td class="info">Total Loss<br />Given Default</td>
    <td class="info">% Loss<br />Guarantee</td>
    <td class="info">Total Loss<br />After Guarantee</td>
    <td class="info">% Loss</td>
    <td class="info">Note LGD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr632">
    <td><em>GGA 01</em></td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  ...more rows...
</table>
```

EDIT 2:
I found the answer. In my CSS for my table, I specified a background color for the td tags in the table. I removed this and set the background color in the tr tags instead. Now it works. It looks like the CSS for the td tag was overwriting jQuery.

Comment: Nope, not getting an error. Just isn't working.

Comment: Make sure id is right. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/GmAAM/).

Comment: If your `tr>td` is empty then it might not work because you can't see it.

Comment: Can you post your html code for the table ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I opened your example and it displayed just fine. I copied your code and pasted it into mine and the highlight would not work. No errors show up either.

Comment: Works fine as long as the ID exists: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eANJH/

Comment: I have verified the ID exists. I can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: You have more rows in the table. Verify the <tr> and <td> tags are properly closed.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the table into jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KmbTg/). It displays fine here, just won't display on my end. I used fadein and that worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In my CSS for my table, I specified a background color for the td tags in the table. I removed this and set the background color in the tr tags instead. Now it works. It looks like the CSS for the td tag was overwriting jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include UI? That's the only difference I'm seeing: [jsFiddle Example (click on/off UI include)](http://jsfiddle.net/geF9y/1/) This would be in keeping with the fact that `fadein` would work...because `fadein` is included in the main jquery library whereas `.effect` is a UI component.

Comment: Yes, I was including jQuery UI.